# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Bangkok?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand, bangkok

I am an Indian citizen currently studying in Australia on a student visa. In November 2019, I am travelling to India for vacation and I have booked a ticket from Melbourne to Bangkok and then from Bangkok to India with a layover time of 7 hours in Bangkok. I will not be leaving the airport, but my flights are different.

Do I need to get an Airport Transit Visa in Bangkok?

Comment: Did you book a single itinerary or two separate tickets and will you have checked baggage?

Answer (score 1):

No, for a period less than 12 hours a Indian citizen does not seem to need a Transit visa for Thailand.

---

[The Royal Thai Embassy in Australia](http://canberra.thaiembassy.org/Home/visa)

- type **India** in Box for **Passport of which Country do you hold?**

  - select **Transit Visa** from result

and all information you need can be seen.

The site is very easy to use

- wish other countries would make it as easy

---

The statement above is based on the following entry from the above result:

A Transit Visa is needed when:

> Transiting through Thailand’s airports exceeding 12 hours before proceeding to a third country of destination or returning to your home country - Category “TS” (Requiring a copy of outbound ticket to a third country)

Otherwise read the very extensive information offered should other conditions exists.