# Do I need a transit Visa in Bangkok? Travelling from Singapore to Lucknow and transit at Bangkok

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, transit-visas, thailand

I'm travelling from Singapore to Lucknow (India) with transit at Bangkok. Here are the flight details:

Singapore - Bangkok : Thai Airways
Bangkok - Lucknow : Thai Smile

Do I need a transit visa at Bangkok? I am getting mixed info that's why seeking more info if someone had travelled this route before.

I have travelled from Singapore to other Europe, India and Japan before and both legs were on Thai Airways and I didnt require a transit visa at BKK.

But in this instance, my second leg is on Thai Smile so not sure probably they follow the same rules.

Comment: What country are you a citizen of?

Comment: Oh sorry. Missed this info. I am an Indian Citizen. And booking both flights in the same ticket (assuming it should be under same PNR)

Comment: see answer here: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/144911/95267

Answer (score 1):

This itinerary requires a visa. Transit without visa through Thailand is not possible when flying on low cost carriers such as Thai Smile. You must clear immigration in both directions to change flights, even without checked baggage.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in part:

> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through
>   Bangkok (BKK) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a
>   third country within 12 hours. They must stay in the
>   international transit area of the airport and have documents
>   required for the next destination.
>
> - This TWOV facility does not apply to passengers traveling
>     on Angkor Air (K6), Beijing Capital Airlines (JD), Business
>     Air (8B), Cebu Pacific (5J), Eaststar Jet (ZE), Golden
>     Myanmar Airlines (Y5), Indigo (6E), Jeju Air (7C), Jet Asia
>     Airways (JF), Jetstar (JQ), Jetstar Pacific (BL), Jin Air
>     (LJ), JuneYao Airlines (HO), Lao Central Airlines (LF),
>     Mandara Airlines (RI), Norwegian Air (DY), Okay Airways
>     (BK), Orient Thai Airlines (OX), Regent Air (RX), Scoot
>     (TR), Shandong Airlines (SC), Shanghai Airlines (FM),
>     Shenzhen Airlines (ZH), Siberia Airlines (S7), Sichuan
>     Airlines (3U), South East Asian Airlines (DG), Spice Jet
>     (SG), Thai Smile Airlines (WE), Tianjin Airlines (GS),
>     Trans Aero (UN), Turkmenistan Airlines (T5), T'way Airlines
>     (TW), Ural Airlines (U6) and VietJet Air (VJ).

You can [obtain the e-visa in advance](https://www.evisathailand.com/en/), to save time at Thai immigration.

Comment: This is for the benefit for those who are travelling this itinerary. I can confirm that you DONT require a Thai visa at BKK if you have booked both legs under the same "Reservation code" and your luggage is thru check in at SG. (as on 23rd Sep 2019)