# Do Indian citizens need a transit visa for Japan and Thailand?

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, japan, thailand

Two international connections from Canada to India via Tokyo and Bangkok. I am indian citizen and working in canada as i have open work permit of canada. So my question is can i travel to india via Tokyo (1hour 30min)  Bangkok (7hour 35min). With these timings of layover at airports do i need any kind of visa or can i travel without any restrictions?

Comment: JAL do not fly from Bangkok to India

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9027/layover-at-narita-japan-do-i-need-a-transit-visa and  https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/144910/do-i-need-a-transit-visa-for-a-layover-in-bangkok